# SyntaxError: Unexpected token > in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

I just started learning Coffeescript and have syntax error that I can't figure out. I have written the following code:

```
exports.list = (req, res) ->
  User.find({}).select('username').exec (err, results) ->
    if err
      res.send(err)
    else
      console.log(results)
      viewData = 
        title: 'Users'
        users: results

      res.render 'users', viewData
    return
  return
```

When executed it throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token > on line 1`, but as far as I know this should be the right syntax for Coffeescript?

Comment: [Looks fine to me.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:exports.list%20%3D%20%28req%2C%20res%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20User.find%28%7B%7D%29.select%28'username'%29.exec%20%28err%2C%20results%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20err%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res.send%28err%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28results%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20viewData%20%3D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20'Users'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20users%3A%20results%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res.render%20'users'%2C%20viewData%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20return)

Comment: @OlehPrypin So you think there might be something with me environment why it is not working? I am using the latest release of Node.js with Express and Mongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**The code is valid CoffeeScript.**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aexports.list%20%3D%20%28req%2C%20res%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20User.find%28%7B%7D%29.select%28%27username%27%29.exec%20%28err%2C%20results%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20err%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res.send%28err%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28results%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20viewData%20%3D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%27Users%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20users%3A%20results%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res.render%20%27users%27%2C%20viewData%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20return)

It appears that whatever is executing this code is expecting JavaScript, not CoffeeScript. By pasting your code into a JavaScript console I got the exact same error.